# Let $f(x)$ determine value of $g(x)$ in terms of $f(x)$

Tags: integration

Let $f(x)$ determine the value of $g(x)$ in terms of $f(x),$ my teacher tells me that the solution is between sustitution, i attemped $u = \log(x) \,du = \frac{1}{x}\,dx$, $dx = e^u\,du$, also my teacher says that the interval of integration won't be the same but it's possible to split the integral, sorry im not native english speaker lol

$$f(x) = \int_0^x e^{e^t} \, dt$$
$$g(x) =\int_2^3 \frac{dx}{\log(x)}$$

Comment: Please write a more descriptive of what you are looking for and show that your attempt at solving this.

Comment: valor: noun, *great courage in the face of danger, especially in battle.*

Comment: In Spanish, however, valor means value.  Please clarify your question, in English.

Comment: i already clarify my post, sorry